# PHP Making Time variables? 5 for the hour and then echo it back?

Tags: php, date, time

Just a quick question, how would I be able to edit the following Date/Time variable to PLUS(+) the hour number 5, at the moment it's in US time, I need to convert everything to UK time.

`$tme = date('H:i : d F Y');`

Any ideas...?

Comment: R.T.F.M http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Comment: @nonshatter: It's not obvious to someone using normal date functions that `DateTime` exists, let alone that there's a `setTimezone()` method for it.

Answer (score 6):

Use `DateTime` objects, it's more robust and will give you less headaches:

```
$time = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
$time->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone("Europe/London"));

echo $time->format("H:i:s Y-m-d");
```

Also note that with this, you can deal with weird timezone related oddities (such as some timezones changing in different dates, some are dependent of years etc) without doing any sort of computation, the DateTimeZone object does it for you :-)

Comment: Ah.. you beat me to it. :-)  +1

Comment: Perfect answer! setting the default timezone is often not desired, this is way better.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the top of your page:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use date_default_timezone_set function

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tme = date('H:i : d F Y', time() + 60*5);
```

but you may be interested in [DateTime object](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

or change timezone using

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone` instead:

```
// U.S. timezone (EST)
$tme = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $tme->format('H:i : d F Y');

// U.K. timezone
$tme->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
echo $tme->format('H:i : d F Y');
```